# Get events within first 10 minutes

Tags: wso2, siddhi

I'm new to the `Siddhi` language. I need to get events only within the first 10 minutes of an event stream. Is there a way to do this task?
Here is the defined input stream.

```
define stream InputDataStream (timestamp long, obd2_MAF float, obd2_engine_rpm float);
```

Answer (score 0):

there's no way to get the events in the 1st 10 min in CEP as at now

siddhi time window will slide and keep the events of last 10 minutes in it.

one option you have is to create a siddhi query and ignore events that has time stamp value greater that 10 minutes + the time stamp of the very first event, this could be achieved using a filter query.

please refer [1] for this

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP210/Filters